# Angular 4 : SharedModule Causing Error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-module

i have a **sharedModule** that has a service called **ConfigService** and using the **forRoot()** pattern:

**shared.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';// resolve ENV variable

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers:[]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot():ModuleWithProviders{
    return{
      ngModule:SharedModule,
      providers:[ConfigService]
    }
  }
 }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    AuthModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**when i'm trying to inject the ConfigService in another module Service
(AuthModule -> AuthService) - i'm  receiving the following Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forChild' of undefined
    at Object.cDNt (main.d647daef485a4cf9cf6d.bundle.js:1)
    at n (inline.7c624a7372e785c7b8fb.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.0 (main.d647daef485a4cf9cf6d.bundle.js:1)
    at n (inline.7c624a7372e785c7b8fb.bundle.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (inline.7c624a7372e785c7b8fb.bundle.js:1)
    at main.d647daef485a4cf9cf6d.bundle.js:1
```

**AuthService.ts:**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private ConfigService:ConfigService) { 

  }
```

i can't resolve what causing this error.

Comment: Perhaps this may help https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#configure-core-services-with-coremoduleforroot

Comment: What is the purpose of AuthModule.forRoot() call?

Comment: where do you call forChild() ?